# Ask about function and default value

Tags: php

Good day.

We have code:

```
<?php
return func('2');

function func($def = 'hi'){

if($def == '2'){$def = $_POST['hello'];}
else {$def = 'no';}

echo $def;

}
?>
```

In result we see 'no';

Tell me please how use right default value in `function func($def = 'hi')`?

Comment: What you trying to achieve ? What is your expecting output ?

Comment: https://eval.in/118467 it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
<?php
return func();
```

But i must to note, that your function func does'nt return any value, so string return func(); has no sense

Answer (score 0):

To start, I am not sure why you are using `return` in the beginning of the code.

Default values are only used when no arguments are passed to the function, like in `func()`. If you call anything `func('3')`, the $def will be `'3'`.

Also, I can't say the value of the `$_POST['hello']` you posted, as this is apparently in a web environment? If `$_POST['hello']` happens to be the value 'no', you will also see no in the output...

If you could add more details, it would help!

Comment: i would like how set default value for element function, in my example $def

Comment: You are already doing that... Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default